# Haskell: Working with errors/exceptions in Haskell

Tags: haskell

He guys, I have a problem. I have two functions in my Haskell program.

```
type Env =  String -> Int

emptyEnv :: Env
emptyEnv _ = error "Failed"

insertEnv :: String -> Loc -> Env -> Env
insertEnv s loc env = case env s of
                      (error "Failed") -> (\inp -> (if inp==s then loc else env s))
                      _ -> env
```

So my emptyEnv should always give an error message. With the other function insertEnv you can insert elements to Env. But therefore you need to check if Env is empty and this will display an error on screen. Now my question: The code above doesn't work because error "Failed" is not a case of env s in the function insertEnv. Do you have an idea how I handle the error properly so that you can insert elements to env?

Answer (score 3):

We usually handle failing functions in Haskell by them returning a `Maybe` type:

```
type Loc = Int
type Env = String -> Maybe Loc -- Here

emptyEnv :: Env
emptyEnv _ = Nothing
```

And for `insertEnv` we would write:

```
insertEnv :: String -> Loc -> Env -> Env
insertEnv s loc env inp =
  case env inp of
    Nothing ->
      if s == inp
        then Just loc
        else Nothing
    Just loc' -> Just loc'
```

Which follows your intended meaning by not making an insert update the `Env`. Another possibility for `insertEnv` is to "update" the environment:

```
insertEnv' :: String -> Loc -> Env -> Env
insertEnv' key loc env inKey
  | key == inKey = Just loc
  | otherwise = env inKey
```

---

If you're interested, both versions can be implemented using the [`First`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-7.15/base-4.9.0.0/Data-Monoid.html#t:First) and [`Last`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-7.15/base-4.9.0.0/Data-Monoid.html#t:Last) wrappers from `Data.Monoid`.

```
import Data.Monoid

type Env' = String -> First Loc -- Choose First or Last here

emptyEnv' :: Env'
emptyEnv' _ = mempty

insertEnv' :: String -> Loc -> Env' -> Env'
insertEnv' s loc env inp =
  env inp <>
  if s == inp
    then pure loc
    else mempty
```

With some environment

```
env1 = insertEnv' "1" 2 (insertEnv' "1" 1 emptyEnv')
```

If you pick `First` with the above implementation you get

```
GHCI> env1 "1"
First {getFirst = Just 1}
```

or with `Last`

```
GHCI> env1 "1"
Last {getLast = Just 2}
```

Comment: Thanks adamse. Quickly off-topic. Now I tried it just with `emptyEnv = \_->(-1)` and `insert s loc env = \inp ->(if inp==s then loc else env s)` but now when I do this `env = insert "x" 42 (insert "y" 17 emptyEnv)` and then `env "y"` it gives me -1 so the vale of an empty Env. Whats going on there? It worked 5 minutes ago!?

Comment: You want `... else env inp`.

Answer (score 2):

> With the other function `insertEnv` you can insert elements to `Env`. But therefore you need to check if `Env` is empty.

Why do you need to check if an environment is empty before you insert something into it? An environment containing the variable `x` is just a function that, if given the name `x`, returns the value to which `x` was bound.

```
insertEnv s loc env = \v -> if v == s then loc else env v
```